# Working with my leaderboard. Possible to minimize workload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got stat model :

```
Stat(id: integer, points: float, user_id: integer, match_id: integer, team_id: integer)
```

For match model:

```
 Match(id: integer, team_a_id: integer, team_b_id: integer)
```

Here's my code now:

```
stat= Stat
.group(:user_id)
.select("user_id, count(*) as matches_count, sum(points) as score")
.where.not(points: 0)
.where.not(match_id: nil)

stat.each do |f|
  new_value = (f.sum_points.to_f / f.matches_count.to_f)
  f.sum_points = new_value.round(2)
  a << f
end

new_stat = a.sort_by(&:sum_points).reverse.first(10).flatten
```

I have to change the value of `sum_points` on each data what if I got a lot of data so it will take time is there a way to minimize it? What I need is the first top 10.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ you are abusing `each` for actual _mapping_. It should be (instead of the whole `stat.each`): `stat.map { |f| (f.sum_points.to_f / f.matches_count.to_f).round(2) }`.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, do the math, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 10` in the database.

Comment: I already get this limit using this code `new_stat = a.sort_by(&:sum_points).reverse.first(10).flatten` I replaced my code with your code `.map`. Thank you.

Comment: `a.sort_by.reverse` does the sorting and reversing in ruby, which is extremely inefficient. That all should be done in the DB enforcing only 10 necessary rows to be returned from the DB to Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to compute the data using the sql and only retrieve the top 10.

Basically, right now you're manually parsing the whole active record array to compute the sum_points and then you're sorting and reversing all of the data to retrieve the top 10. Like you've said, the performance will suffer when large amount of data will be in the database.

Here's my solution that will compute and retrieve the top 10 using only sql queries:

```
stat = Stat.group(:user_id)
.select("user_id, round((sum(points) /count(*)), 2) as sum_points")
.where.not(points: 0).where.not(match_id: nil).order("sum_points DESC").first(10)
```

Comment: I'm getting the correct points but I've got another problem `count(*)` gives the number of record. So if there is 53 records I get /53 what i need is by match_id which is number of games played.

Comment: In our case the count is computed based on the group, that being said, within that select `count(*)` returns the number of records within that group(as in: the number of stats of an user), it doesn't return the number of all of the Stats in the database.
If you want the number of matches within that group, use `count(match_id)` instead of `count(*)`, if you want the distinct matches use `COUNT(DISTINCT match_id)`.